# Quadratic Programming in Julia

Tags: optimization, quadratic-programming, julia-jump

Well, I have a quadratic programming optimization problem, well structured in Matlab. For instance, 
With `x` a `n*1` vector, we have

```
x = argmin (1/2*x'*H*x+f'*x)
s.t.
A*x <= b
x_lb<=x<=x_ub
```

Of course, `A` is a matrix and `b`, `x_lb`, `x_ub` are vectors.
However, my question is, how to construct such a standard in Julia
I tried with Jump.
Actually,

```
A*x .<= b
```

can make the last constiant work. But how to construct the second constraint `x_lb<=x<=x_ub` in JuMP? I tried with

```
[x_lb[i]<=x[i]<=x_ub[i] for i =1:X_dim]
```

but it didn't work. It seems like only constant can be assigned as upper/lower bounds?

Also, for the quadratic objective, "aff" and "quad" can be used but we need to treat `x`, `H` and `f` element-wisely, which makes such a job time-consuming.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: convex.jl would allow the matrix-form description, but there are some trade-offs (should be clear after reading the docs). With JuMP, you can give those bounds at var-declaration time (not necessarily formulated as constraints; probably depends on the solver) like shown in the [docs](http://jump.readthedocs.io/en/latest/refvariable.html).

Comment: Hi Sascha,   you are absolutely right. Convex.jl makes quadratic programming much easier.